# Gravitational field of the star changes the paths of light rays, how is this observed during eclipse?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, gravitational-lensing

The gravitational field of the star changes the paths of light rays in space-time from what they would have been had the star not been present. I understand that the light cones are bend slightly inward near the surface of the star.

But what confuses me is - this can be seen in the bending of light from distant star observed during an eclipse of the sun.

During the eclipse the light from the sun is blocked so the stars are visibly to us but why would it affect the bending of the light from these distant stars as gravitational field of the sun should remain unchanged ?

Comment: A recent question on this topic on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55786/16685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*why would it affect the bending of the light from these distant stars as gravitational field of the sun should remain unchanged*

You are right that the eclipse changes nothing about the gravitational field of the Sun.  But the "curved" path of light from the star to us is only measurable for paths that just graze the Sun's surface.  So it is only during an eclipse that one can observe the effect, when you can see stars right next to the blacked-out Sun. The path the star's light takes to us is *always* bent around the Sun (and straight-line when it is elsewhere in the sky), but during the eclipse you have the opportunity to see the effect.

The astro.SE question linked in the comments is good.  Imagine that you spend a winter tracking a particular star in the night sky (pick one that lies on the "ecliptic", the plane of the solar system, so that later in the year it will go behind the Sun).  From your measurements, you know exactly where it should be in the sky at any time, but those measurements/predictions rely on an assumption that the light from the star takes a straight-line path to us. Six months later, in the summer, that star is in the daytime sky, right next to, or maybe behind, the Sun. Perhaps during the time of the eclipse it emerges from behind the Sun, just because the Earth's motion on its own orbit suddenly brings the star into view.  What you will find is that the star arrived **too early**.  When the Sun is between the Earth and the star, the light bends around the Sun.  While a "straight-line path" to the star would go straight through the Sun, the actual path bends around the corner.

See [this NASA video](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/13260).

[image: screenshot of linked NASA video on bending of starlight around Sun]

Comment: thanks this explains.

Comment: The Sun's angular diameter is ~1900 arc-secs, and the deflection for a "Sun-grazing" ray is only ~1.75 arc-secs. So it's not possible to see a star that's behind the Sun, unless it's *really* close to the rim. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&COMMAND=10&CENTER=0%40399&QUANTITIES=%2713%2C21%27&CAL_TYPE=G&START_TIME=%272024-Jan-1+12%3A00+UT%27&STOP_TIME=2025-Jan-2&STEP_SIZE=1month

Answer (score 1):

The sun is not the same place in the sky all year, relative to the stars. What you do is you first note the position of your chosen star relative to the sky during a time of year when that star appears at night. In practice astronomers have already done this for basically all stars. Then when the eclipse happens, you measure the position of the star and compare it to where the star should be, which you calculate from its known position in the sky as well as the time of year and time of day.

Comment: IIRC: our astrometry is so good now, we can see the solar gravitational affect on all the stars' positions, wherever, whenever...